# How to remove revision files from a perforce proxy

Tags: perforce

I am attempting to remove old revision files from a perforce proxy server. I have found the revisions that I want to remove I just don't know how to actually remove them.

Assuming that I wanted to remove this file from my p4p server how would I go about doing that?

```
//depot/folder/file.txt#12
```

Thank you for the help!

EDIT:
The goal here is not to delete the files entirely but rather to just free up excess HDD space on the proxy by removing revisions that aren't needed on the proxy.

Answer (score 5):

The proxy has no high-level commands for cleaning its cache. Simply sign on to the machine the proxy is running on, locate the cache directory on the filesystem, and remove the files in that directory.

The next time any of your users reference those files via the proxy, the proxy will automatically re-request them from the server, and will re-cache them at that time.

Naturally, you have to sign on to the proxy machine as a user with enough privilege to remove files from the proxy's filesystem. For example, sign on as the user under which the proxy runs.

Note, **don't** obliterate the files! That will remove them from the master server, not from the proxy (worse, it won't even remove them from the proxy, only from the master server!).

Many administrators write simple scripts which clean files in their proxy's cache in an automated fashion, periodically. If you wish to write such a script, you can find examples lying around the web.